# How can I float a div at a fixed height from the top of the container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think this will require javascript. I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask though.

We all know how to float an image or div right or left and have the text flow around and below that image. I'm trying to float a div at a fixed width from the top of a container and have text flow around above and below it.

It would be easiest if I could place this div above the paragraph text, but I could insert it if I had to.

I made this crude image outlining what I'm trying to do.[image: Image outlining the problem]

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need javascript. It can be done using a few div tags. AFAIK, js allows you to manipulate the document, but in this case, you don't need to manipulate the document or execute an action, but to define a layout. I need to meditate on your question ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bit of a cheat but possible using a dummy spacer

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.fl {
float: left;
clear: left;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.fr {
float: right;
clear: right;
margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

.dummy {float: right; height: 300px; width: 1px; background: #f00;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">

<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" width="100" height="100" class="fl">
<span class="dummy"></span>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x200/DAD/fff" width="100" height="200" class="fr">   

<p>all your paragraphs follow</p>
</div>
```

#### Working Example: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/BJ8yR/)

and the spacer does need to be at least 1px wide, but it can be transparent

Comment: This actually works perfectly. I would never have thought to do it that way. Thanks so much, Claire.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/8DczT/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what a `float` does; it puts a box wherever you specify, and content flows around it. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynQpT/).

Comment: It doesn't allow the text to flow around the top of the floated element though. It also doesn't let me stick that element above the content and position it inside the text container. If you look at my example, the floated div is spanning multiple paragraphs, starting at the middle of one, and ending at the middle of the next.

Answer (score 0):

Put a margin-top on your floated div, to push it down from the top, something like this:

```
<div>  <!-- parent containing div -->
    <div style="float: right; margin-top: 50px">floated div</div>
    <div>paragraph 1</div>
    <div>paragraph 2</div>
</div>
```

As long as you get the margin right, you can floa it halfway between the center of the two paragraph divs.